# How can I create a multiplatform (PC/Mac/Linux) USB stick with a Live Linux + webserver on it?

Tags: linux, mac, usb, boot, webserver

The goal woulb de to have a USB stick, bootable on any system, containing a local webserver to host various offline versions of websites. This stick can then be used to show demos of websites to people, even if they don't have an internet connection.

Comment: in short, check out http://www.pendrivelinux.com/ there's ALOT of info there.

Comment: Yep, I see many ways to boot Linux ISOs on USB, the difference is I'd like to "pre-install" my offline websites on an Apache (xampp type) server on an ISO, before burning it on CD / copying on USB for live running, so that the live USB or CD can run my offline stuff by default.

Comment: There's guides for that sort of thing, just alter the image before putting into the usb pen

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Fedora liveusb-creator, it will allow you to create non-volatile space in the USB stick. There you will be able to install applications or store some data.